# Шаблон для категорий

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Подскажите, как можно для вывода категорий товаров вместо **archive-product.php** задать свой шаблон.
И нужно, чтобы для подкатегорий также был свой шаблон
...
Уже нашёл, где можно поменять шаблон категорий. Файл **taxonomy-product_cat.php**

Answer (score 0):

> как можно для вывода категорий товаров вместо archive-product.php задать свой шаблон

Скопировать в каталог `/woocommerce/` своей темы и отредактировать как хочется.
см https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/

Comment: >Скопировать в каталог /woocommerce/ своей темы и отредактировать как хочется.
см https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/

Comment: а если этот файл уже скопирован в свою тему, но нужно чтобы этой файл был по умолчанию для других целей, а именно для категорий нужен новый шаблон?

Comment: Для других целей есть другие шаблоны.

Comment: ну допустим для подкатегорий также нужен свой шаблон.
Какой тогда нужно использовать для этой цели?